# Is there a JavaScript event that fires when a tab index switch is triggered? (TABINDEX does not work for inputs in IFRAME)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

My specific use case is that I have a WYSIWYG editor which is basically an editable iframe. To the user, however, it looks like a standard-issue textarea. My problem is that I have inputs that sit before and after this editor in the (perceived) tab index and I'd like the user to be able to press tab (or the equivalent on his platform of choice) to get to the WYSIWYG editor when he's in the previous element and shift-tab to get to it when he's in the latter element.

I know this can be faked using the key events and checking whether or not the tab key was pressed, but I'm curious if there's a better way.

---

**UPDATE**.  treeface clarified the actual problem in the comments.

**PROBLEM**:

In normal case, you can use "[`TABINDEX`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex)" attribute of the `<input>` element to control that, when tabbing out of "Subject" input field (in an email form), the focus lands on "Body" input field in the e-mail. This is done simply by assigning correctly ordered values to "TABINDEX" attribute of both input fields.

The problem is that TABINDEX attribute only orders elements within the same frame. So, if "Body" input field is actually in an internal `IFRAME`, you can't tab out of "Subject" in the parent frame straight into "Body" in the IFRAME using TABINDEX order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably emulate the desired behavior (probably with less issues than detecting TAB key) by onfocus/onblur events of the relevant input elements. This way you don't CARE how the user got to the editor input, whether it'd be via TABs or clicking or some weird FireFox AddOn which allows you to jump to input element by its ID/name/# (I'm almost certain such add-on exists :)

---

**UPDATE**. OP clarified the problem in the comments.

**PROBLEM**:

In normal case, you can use "[`TABINDEX`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex)" attribute of the `<input>` element to control that, when tabbing out of "Subject" input field (in an email form), the focus lands on "Body" input field in the e-mail. This is done simply by assigning correctly ordered values to "TABINDEX" attribute of both input fields.

The problem is that TABINDEX attribute only orders elements within the same frame. So, if "Body" input field is actually in an internal `IFRAME`, you can't tab out of "Subject" in the parent frame straight into "Body" in the IFRAME using TABINDEX order.

**SOLUTION**:

In the parent frame, create a new `<INPUT>` element. It will be invisible (e.g. via CSS or making size 1x1), will have name/id of "Body_clone", and will have the TABINDEX attribute value which follows the TABINDEX of "Subject" field. It will also have an onFocus handler which will simply find the "Body" input element inside the IFRAME and call `focus()` on that element.

You can do the same with tabbing/shift-tabbing out of IFRAME "Body" element by creating "Subject_iframe_clone" and "After-body_iframe_clone" input elements in the IFRAME which work just like "Body_clone" did.

Comment: @DVK: That's what I thought at first, but after looking through the event object that gets passed into the focus/blur event handlers, I can't seem to find any information about what key was pressed (or if a click occurred or anything).

Comment: @DVK: My point is that there doesn't appear to be a way to distinguish a `blur` caused by clicking outside the element (a normal `blur`) and a `blur` caused by pressing the tab key inside the element.

Comment: @treeface - ok, let me see if I got it. You want to catch a TAB from WITHIN focused textarea, so that instead of tabbing out to the next element it prints "TAB" or something. Correct?

Comment: @DVK: Sure, but let's say I have an element before the editor and an element after the editor. If I set up blur and focus callbacks on these elements, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to distinguish that a blur occurred because of a tab key being pressed or because the user simply clicked something entirely unrelated to the WYSIWYG editor. Furthermore, the event object passed into the callbacks for these events don't seem to give access to a `keyCode` property to test anything against.

Comment: @DVK: Sorry for the confusion...I'm using an unconventional form that has an iframe in it. In order to preserve the UI flow, I want it such that when a user presses "tab" (or the equivalent on his platform) in the regular input box that comes *before* the WYSIWYG iframe, the text cursor moves to the iframe. Similarly, when the user presses shift-tab from the normal input element *after* the WYSIWYG editor, it should place the text cursor in the iframe.

Comment: @DVK: You can see this sort of functionality in GMail when you're composing a new email. The `To:` field is a textarea, the `Subject:` field is a text input, but the content of the message is an editable iframe. Despite this, tabbing to the content field works as expected (from the user's point of view). Basically, I'm trying to figure out if there's a more elegant way to handle this beside capturing keystrokes.

Comment: @treeface - am I correct in assuming that the problem you're facing is that the iframe can't be placed into the correct tabbing order (which determines what input gets focused after tabbing out of last input)?

Comment: @treeface `e.keyCode` works only on key-events. You can bind a handler to the keydown-event to detect if the TAB key is being pressed.

Comment: @treeface - if i'm correct, you can create a "shadow" input element (invisible via CSS or 1x1 size) in the main frame that has a correct tabbing order and whose "onfocus" handler changes the focus to the iframe editor instead. Do the same in the iframe by creating "shadow" input elements that automatically focus on corresponding before/after inputs outside the iframe.

Comment: @DVK: Ah ha! Now you're thinking directly outside the box. I'm going to give this a try and report back.

Comment: @treeface - I distilled the idea into answer update. Hopefully it's clear enough :)

Comment: @DVK: And thanks for editing my question. Very useful for posterity's sake :-]